# Initial separation of neutron star/black hole binaries?

Tags: astronomy, astrophysics, stars, statistics

How would I go about finding the distribution of initial separations (i.e. the lengths between the centres of mass) of stars that make up binary systems. I am interested in neutron stars and stellar black holes.

[This](http://iopscience.iop.org/0004-637X/652/1/540/fulltext/63576.text.html) paper uses an assumption that

> "The initial separation of a binary is chosen from a distribution that is assumed to be logarithmically flat: $\Gamma(A) \propto 1/A$."

but it neither defines $\Gamma$ or $A$, so yeah... helpful.

Comment: Looks to me they're calling the distribution $\Gamma$ and calling the separation $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paper is rather lacking in definitions, I'll give you that.

As Murphrid points out, $\Gamma$ is just the PDF for separation, and $A$ is the variable used for the separation itself. The constant of proportionality is set by requiring the total probability to be unity.

Of course, as defined $\Gamma$ is not normalizable - it diverges logarithmically for both $A \to 0$ and $A \to \infty$. Presumably they put in a cutoff (much as they have a mass distribution $\Psi(M) \propto M^{-2.7}$, but they cut it off at $4~M_\odot$ and $100~M_\odot$), but I couldn't find any reference to the values.

The take-away message is that our understanding of the initial distributions of star properties still needs a lot of work. We can hardly claim to understand the [distribution of initial masses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_mass_function) beyond rough empirical measurements, and binary mass ratios (assumed to be uniform on $[0, 1]$ in this paper) and binary separations are at least as elusive. The assumptions in this paper were made so as to have *something* to feed into the simulations - they should by no means be taken to be the *actual* distributions of parameters.